# Voltage stabilizer or voltage protection device for irrigation setup

Tags: relay, low-voltage, fluid-pump, undervoltage

I have an irrigation setup in a rural area with voltage fluctuations.

The irrigation setup consists of a Hunter X2 Controller powering a pump start relay which in turn runs a 1.5 HP submersible motor at around 280 feet.

The pump operates well when the pump controller displays a voltage over 200 V (AC single-phase) after starting the motor. However, when the pump runs at a displayed voltage of 170 V the relay heats up and chatters.

Due to the nature of supply in rural areas I would like to mitigate this condition. My search yielded two options:

1. Voltage stabilizer
2. [Voltage protection device with under and over voltage cutoff](https://www.amazon.in/dp/B0BWRGTLJ7)

I am looking for advice on my analysis as well as the solution option to finalise.

Comment: If that is 200V AC, consider a solid state relay.  They turn on and off with a very small draw.  Only down side is the ones I'm thinking of can't be used on DC (although their on off signal can be).

Comment: if it's the trigger condition switching too much, maybe more hysteresis on the trigger condition might help ? Is that something the controller can do?  ... or if it is it an undervoltage issue, which makes the controller pull more current, then adding or raising the undervoltage threshold?

Comment: I’m a total noob as far electrical engineering is concerned. So please excuse me if my response is incomplete.This is 220V AC single phase line. The irrigation controller triggers the relay via DC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> at around 280 feet

Is that depth or horizontal distance?

---

1. An electromechanical relay designed for 230-240V nominal won't pull in reliably at 170V as you've noticed. Use a solid-state relay (SSR). Make sure you put it on a heatsink as per the datasheet.
2. At too low of a voltage, the motor may stall or not develop enough head pressure to keep the water moving in the pipe. In either case, the motor will be dissipating the entire electrical power it consumes as heat into the stagnant water inside the pump. The pump head will overheat. Depending on construction, the water inside may boil, plastic parts may get damaged, as can bearing seals, o-rings, etc.

I wouldn't worry much about persistent overvoltage. That doesn't really happen all that much. Undervoltage is a real concern for you, and for that you'd want an undervoltage protection relay.

Something [similar to this device](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08R8TPB25), but preferably from a major brand and a major distributor of industrial controls, rather than non-name unsupported products from Amazon where your only remedy is maybe a return.

If you decide to go with the Amazon deal, it may be worth buying a couple of them, preferably looking differently so that hopefully if one has some design or production mistake, the other one won't.

But you'll do well to peruse legit industrial automation brands and distributors, and consider buyer beware on anything from Amazon, eBay, AliExpress, etc.

Comment: Thank you for a detailed response. The pump is at a depth of 280 feet.I had a tough time looking for an options from standard brands. But I will take your advice and visit some dealers/distributors instead of going with the Amazon option. Voltage stabilizers from leading brands are available though. So are they worth considering or should I got for a solid state relay + heat sink and a under voltage protection relay?